# How to validate phone number using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having already a script for validate email below

```
function validateEmail(email){ 
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if(re.test(email)){
    document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor ='#80c75a';
    document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor ='#e35152';
    return false;
  }
}
```

I need a script that validates a phone number. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What type of phone number are we talking about? From which country/region?

Comment: thnx for the early reply I am from india.

Comment: Can you give us some valid phone numbers?

Comment: I need a phone number validation with same error indication as mentioned in the javascript above. can u help me?

Comment: @Mr.Wolf , 0484 0000000 (tel) 0000000000 (mob) formats

Comment: Please don't. Unless you want to make sure to annoy your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this.May  be this is what you want.

```js
function validatePhone(phone) {
    //var re=/^(\+91-|\+91|0)?\d{10}$/;//for pattern like +91-9198387083,9198387083,09198387083
    var re = /^\d{10}$/; //for exact 10 digits
    var re1 = /^(\d{4}\s)?\d{7}$/; // for phone if you don't need space remove \s
    if (re.test(phone)) {
        document.getElementById('phone').style.borderColor = '#80c75a';
        //document.getElementById('phoneError').style.display = "none";
        return true;
    } else if (re1.test(phone)) {

        document.getElementById('phone').style.borderColor = '#80c75a';
    } else {

        document.getElementById('phone').style.borderColor = '#e35152';
        return false;
    }
}

$("#phone").on("blur", function () {
    validatePhone($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone" "/>
```

for more you can visit [here](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php)

Comment: ,@ozil..thnx both of you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if the provided string is a number:

```
var isPhoneNumber = /^\d+$/.test(val);
```

Secondly you could check the length:

```
isPhoneNumber.length == indial_phone_number_lenght
```

Then you could check if the prefix of the number is in the your array of possible indian phone number prefixes

Comment: @ansarmon you can edit @aurelius answer to: `var tel = /^\d{11}$/.test('04840000000');` and `var mob = /^\d{10}$/.test('0000000000');`. Valid `tel` phone number has length equal to 11, it's 10 for valid `mob` phone number

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
function isValidNumber(telephoneNumber){
    var validator = /(\d{3})-*(\d{8})/;
    var results = telephoneNumber.search(validator) > -1 ? true: false;

    return results;
}
```

As shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qhft3q6s/)